# Azure Graph Api Fetch External User's Information

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I set up a webhook for Azure Graph [CallRecords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta) to capture data on Teams calls. All of the data comes back perfect.

There is though one instance I don't know how to handle. Having a Teams call with external user, not part of our AD. The CallRecord response return a object as follow for the external user:

```
"user": {
            "id": "<user-id>",
            "displayName": "External user",
            "tenantId": "<tenant-id>"
        }
```

I though that since we invited the person to our call he will be automatically be added as a guest user to our AD. But seems not to be the case. So we can't link that external user to substantial information like an email. I tried running a graph user api query; But it return resource not found.

Am I missing something, is there a way I can query the external user's information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In teams, there's a difference between a guest user and an external user. a guest user is a user that someone has added to any team in your tenant and thus your azure ad tenant. an external user is a user already on teams or skype but not in your tenant. they are federated only and can only call and chat, cannot send files or join a team.  in order to have a user in your azure ad, that user must be added to a team or manually added as a guest in your azure ad. if you just chat or call an external federated user without adding them to your tenant, it's simply an federated chat/call with no relation whatsoever with your tenant. 
through graph api or any other means you won't be able to get very much information from those users that are externally federated. whereas you will be able to do basically full reporting on a guest users.

hopefully this helps clarify.

**update**
once you add them as a guest, they have to accept and join your tenant as a guest. then in their teams they will have the option to select your tenant. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you. Thus, if we want to do reporting on External User, we should first add them to our AD as a guest or user?

Comment: you would add them as an external guest. but in teams client, they would have to call from your tenant. I updated the post with a screenshot of the experience they would have to call from. so they would have to click the tenant and select your organization (guest) to call from there, then call will be reportable within your tenant. if they call from their original tenant, then your original problem would occur.  if you really want to track everything like that, i would almost suggest you implement a policy to either disable or limit external users to your teams tenant and only allow guests.

Comment: unfortunately, you can't really report much on external users at all. and once they are a guest, they need to select your tenant to be calling as a "guest" and not an external user.. it would be nice if you can report on external users but I guess that may create privacy issues, since external users never have to give consent for your org to monitor them.